# Elements of $L^p$ as Equivalent Classes.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Considering $L^p$ $( 1 \leq  p < \infty)$ as a normed vector space, each element of $L^p$ is actually an Equivalent class. Take $[f] \in L^p $ as an Equivalent class, What is the **Nicest** possible function $g$ such that $g \in [f]$ (i.e. $g=f$ almost everywhere).

By the word **Nice** your free to consider any good topological or algebraic property like continuity, differentiability, boundedness, etc... (as many as you can)

Second question: Let $N$ denotes the set of such **Nice** Properties, imposing $N$ as set of conditions on $g$, can one identify $g$ uniquely ? In other words can we rewrite  $L^p$ in following way

$$L^p = \lbrace g \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \cup \lbrace \pm \infty\rbrace  \mid  \|g\|_P < \infty,~g \text{ satisfies }~N    \rbrace$$

This makes we can think about  $L^p$ as a set of nice functions, free of any confusing equivalent classes.

Comment: By Lusin's theorem, we can take $g$ to be continuous except possibly on very small sets. More rigorously, for any $\epsilon >0$ and any compact set $A$, we can find a set $A_\epsilon$ such that $g$ is continuous on $A \setminus A_\epsilon$ and $\lvert A_\epsilon \rvert < \epsilon$. Also since a $p$-integrable function is finite a.e., we can take $g$ to be finite (but not necessarily bounded).

Comment: Right, but still it doesn't mean $g \in [f]$, I want to replace $[f]$ by a nice function while don't change the space $L^P$.

Comment: That's what I'm saying: given $f$, we can find $g \in [f]$ with the properties I listed above.

Comment: Aha,  makes sense , thanks.

Comment: There are likely better properties that $g$ can satisfy but I'm not sure.

Comment: My intention  is to find a set of finite  conditions called $N$, when we imposing them, we determine $g$ uniquely to replace  $[f]$ by a nice $g$, to rewrite $L^p$ as above.  What is $N$ in your answer? I am not actually happy with  saying on very small set, (we can't fix $\epsilon$).

Comment: I don't claim to have found such $N$.

Comment: Using Zorn + Lusing's Lemma, Can we claim that for each equivalent class, say $[f] \in L^P $  there is a Maximal set, say $A \subseteq R$ or $[0,1]$ such that for this set there is a $ g \in [f] $ which is continuous on $A$ ?  ( in order to get rid of $\epsilon$ )